# Flutter - If get this keyword in the title from a push notification do this action

Tags: flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications, native

I'd like to be able to do actions when receiving specific keywords in the title of notifications coming from specific apps. I've read about the notifications package and notificationlistener. The first one says that it can just give me the app name and timestamp, but I don't understand if it would fit my needs, and the second one (notificationlistener) I'm not sure it could solve my issue.

How can I do what I want? Let's say I receive a notification containing in the title "Breaking News" and I want to copy paste the title and the notification content in my app automatically every time I receive that, how do I do that?

I'm very new to Flutter, so, please explain easily what I should do and if it's feasible in Flutter without recurring to native code.

Comment: you can achieve this the two way, one is android notification listener, another is android accessibility, you need to implement it through platform channel or find and existing package which does that

Comment: There is the notifications package which allows that but it shows the app name and the timestamp and that's it. Do you know of a package or something easy that does what I want?

Comment: no , i dont know any package, you can implement one if you want, have a look at platform channel of flutter, its not that hard